# $A$ and $B$ are finite sets. Proof $\#A+\#B=\#A\cup B +\#A\cap B$ (solved)

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

The title it's self explanatory. I've tried a few things but I don't know where to start. I think that with a hint I can proof this and a written formal proof to compare my answer would be nice too. 
obs: $\#$ means cardinality of a set.

Edit: Solved just now.

Solution:
Since $A\cup B=(A-B)\cup( B-A) \cup( A \cap B )$ and the intersection of this three sets it's empty, so $\#A\cup B=\#A-B+ \#B-A + \# A \cap B $. Since $A=(A-B) \cup (A\cap B) $ and $B=(B-A) \cup (A\cap B) $, we have $\#A+\#B=\#(A-B)+\#(B-A)+2\#(A \cap B) $. The conclusion is trivial.

Comment: Disregard my comment (sorry)

Comment: Try considering an arbitrary $x$ in $A\cup B$. Then look at how many times $x$ is counted on each side, depending on whether $x$ is in $A$ but not $B$, $B$ but not $A$, or both $A$ and $B$.

Comment: Let. $E = A \cap B^c$ $F= A \cap B $ $G=B \cap A^2$.  These 3 sets are disjoint and the union of the three is $A \cup B $.  So $|A \cup B|$ = E+F+G.  A = E + F.  B=F+G.  So E+F+G = A +B - F.

Comment: @Showhat, done here. Thanks for the hint.

Comment: You might consider posting your solution as an answer, rather than an edit.